# Delimitar ciertas fechas en un rango con input type=date, datepicker o similar

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

Estoy trabajando con rangos de fechas, para un periodo vacacional, al final resulto que nunca tome en cuenta los sabados, domingos o dias festivos.

ejemplo.

**01-02-2017** && **09-02-2017** lo que es igual a **8 dias** de vacaciones en este caso, pero 4 y 5 de feb cae sabado y domingo entonces sobre ese rango descontar dos dias que daria un igual a **6 dias** hablies mas **10 y 13** de de febrero viernes y lunes respectivamente para cumplir con **los 8 dias** equivalentes a los dias antes mencionados.

la cuestion es si en datepicker puedo generar un arreglo con determinadas fechas fines de semana o dias festivos. mi script de diferencia de fechas es el siguiente.

```
$('#f1').on('change',function(){
$('#dias').val('');
var f1= new Date($('#f1').val());
var f2= new Date($('#f2').val());
var fechaResta = f2- f1;
var dias = ((((fechaResta / 1000) / 60) / 60) / 24);
$('#dias').val(!isNaN(dias) ? dias : '');
```

tal vez alguien conozca un script que pueda ayudarme con este problema

Answer (score 1):

Capaz esto te sirva

```
beforeShowDay: function (day) { 
       var day = day.getDay(); 
       if (day == 5 || day == 6) { 
         return [false, "somecssclass"] 
       } else { 
         return [true, "someothercssclass"] 
       } 
     }
```

Lo de beforeShowDay es una función del datepicker de jquery UI y en el if solo cambias los numeros por los dias que necesites que se inhabiliten (Domingo:0,Lunes:1,Martes:2,Miércoles:3...etc)

Comment: Gracias @Hector ahorita mismo lo pruebo. (Y)